# Lodash _.difference returns an empty array

Tags: arrays, lodash

Quick and simple question:

I have two arrays that look like this:

```
var arr1 = [10037, 8812, 2412]
var arr2 = [10037, 8813, 2405, 8815, 2407, 8812, 2412, 2412, 8815]
```

I use lodash `difference()` to generate a new variable:

```
var difference = _.difference(arr1, arr2)
```

I console log `difference` and i am expecting to see something like this:

`[8813, 2405, 8815, 2407,2412,8815]` but instead i get an empty array.

Based on the documentation, difference should give back a new array containing the difference beween the two, so why am i getting a new empty array here? what am i doing wrong?

Thanks for any explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_.difference` returns values from the *first* array that are not present in any of the other arrays passed in.

All values in `arr1` are also present in `arr2`, so the result is an empty array.

Documentation for `_.difference` is available here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference

Comment: Thanks. That's correct, changing the order of the arrays work.